# How to Create Embedded Data Source in SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I want to create **embedded** data source in SSRS 2014 using Visual studio 2013. But there is no item for embedded data source. How I can add it?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an *Embedded Data Source* in the report itself, not in the project.

Create a new report in your project (or use an existing one). Then, in the *Report Data* pane <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+D</kbd>, create a new *Data Source* by right-clicking on the *Data Sources* folder.

Choose *Embedded connection*, the Type and populate the *Connection String* with the settings that are appropriate for connecting to your database.

Afterward, add a new dataset by right-clicking on the *Datasets* folder and choosing *Add dataset*. Choose *Use a dataset embedded in my report*, and pick the data source you created above.

The report will use that embedded connection going forward, at least for this dataset.